# How to change itemrender Button Using DataField values?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, mxml

In my Flex Application DataGrid Like...

```
<mx:DataGrid id="userListDataGrid" x="60" y="40" width="520" height="148" dataProvider="{schedule}" creationComplete="userListDataGrid_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="courseDate" headerText="Date"/>               
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="courseName" headerText="Course Name"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn id="usertype" dataField="userType" headerText="User Type"/>

        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Reminder">
            <mx:itemRenderer>
                <mx:Component>
                    <mx:HBox>
                      <mx:Button id="join" label="Join" borderColor="#5d93b9"
                               color="#04becf">
                      </mx:Button>  
                      <mx:Button id="start" label="Start" borderColor="#5d93b9"
                               color="#04becf">
                      </mx:Button>
                    </mx:HBox>
                </mx:Component>
            </mx:itemRenderer>
        </mx:DataGridColumn>

    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

[image: My DataGrid View]

But How to change Button with respect to DataField value i.e..

```
Host----Start Button
Attendee----JOin Button
```

[image: Final Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen to the dataChange event of your itemRenderer and toggle the visibility of the buttons based on the usertype value.  I'm doing a bit of "Guessing" on your data types here since you didn't provide a sample element.  However, roughly something like this:

```
    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Reminder">
        <mx:itemRenderer>
            <mx:Component>
                <mx:HBox dataChange="onDataChange()">
                  <mx:Script>
                      protected function onDataChange():void{
                         if(data.usertype == 'Host'){
                            join.visible = true;
                            start.visible = false;
                         } else {
                            join.visible = false;
                            start.visible = true;
                         }
                      }
                  </mx:Script>
                  <mx:Button id="join" label="Join" borderColor="#5d93b9"
                           color="#04becf">
                  </mx:Button>  
                  <mx:Button id="start" label="Start" borderColor="#5d93b9"
                           color="#04becf">
                  </mx:Button>
                </mx:HBox>
            </mx:Component>
        </mx:itemRenderer>
    </mx:DataGridColumn>
```

I wrote the code in the browser, so it may not be syntactically correct.

Comment: Thank you for replay... but this code not working if we write Alert box in onDataChange() also not Printing... thats way i'm using outerDocument.onDataChange()... but in that time join and start id's are not visiable...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by saying you're using "outerDocument.onDataChange()".  The dataChange method needs to be inside the renderer; not outside of it; otherwise it won't have access to any of the renderer's children.  Sometimes a single renderer will initialize before data is set; so you may want to check for data being non-null.  Also check to see if join and start are non-null before setting their visibility.

Comment: If you need more than that, I'm  going to have to ask for a runnable sample.  I know my approach is correct as I've done it plenty of times; but there may be something wrong w/ my exact code.